# header("Location: mypage.php") not working after upload to other server

Tags: php, twitter, header

In my page I used header location for redirection in twitter login. But it is working fine in my server. But it is not working after uploaded the files to other server

`header("Location: login-twitter.php");`

When try to see what error in the page and used the below code, I see the following warning message.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output 
started at /vhosts/www/samplehosts/mysite.com/samplefolder/header.php:258) in 
/vhosts/www/samplehosts/mysite.com/samplefolder/signin.php on line 24

The redirection is not working on any of the pages in my site. Anybody can help me to solve this problem

**signin.php**

```
if (array_key_exists("login", $_GET)) {

    $oauth_provider = $_GET['oauth_provider'];

    if ($oauth_provider == 'twitter') {

error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); 

        header("Location: login-twitter.php");

    }

}



<li class="twitter">
<a  class="twitter_login" href="?login&oauth_provider=twitter"  rel="nofollow">
<img src="images/twitter.png" width="206" height="33" >
</a>
</li>
```

But after click the twitter button just it shows the header URL as

http://mysite.com/?login&oauth_provider=twitter

and not redirecting to twitter login page.

Comment: the warning says something about some data being sent before the redirection ie probably whitespace; or there must be no output before redirection should occur

Comment: I cant understand what's the warning says about the page. in signin.php the 24th line is "header("Location: login-twitter.php");"

Comment: @Rithu What is in the file `header.php` on line 258? It seems something on this line is outputting something.

Comment: i think you should redirect before even outputting those header php `/vhosts/www/samplehosts/mysite.com/samplefolder/header.php` ie change the order of the scripts have the redirection first before outputting the header file

Comment: @jadkik94 on line 258, there is a commented line in header.php

Comment: @Rithu have the redirection first before having anything outputted on the browser

Comment: @Rithu That's weird... Is it necessary for you to include that file `header.php` *before* the code you posted here? Or can you add it after that?

Comment: @jadkik94 that was what i was saying

Comment: In header file I have 3 conditions for normal, face and twitter users. From that header only the sign in page is called

Comment: @Rithu from what file did you call the header file?

Comment: @iance From index.php the header file is called

Comment: @Rithu ok so basically from the ones that you have listed as the errors/warning investigate on those files and find which have output something before the redirection occurs.start on these `header.php:Line` 258 and `signin.php on line 24`

Comment: @ianace but these redirections working fine in my server. Then why it is not working in other servers. Not only the twitter redirection the site pages contains redirections in several pages they are also not working

Comment: @Rithu You are saying line 258 is commented? There is no way PHP is telling you output started on a commented line. Check that file on the server directly. Maybe you forgot to upload the updated file or something.

Comment: ok I will upload again the header.php file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per my understanding, your problem is that:

```
header("location:[XYX.PHP]") is not working.
```

It generally does not work due to some output is print already on the page.
Please use

> ob_start();

at very the beginning of the page.
This starts output buffering.
And the redirection works.

Answer (score 5):

You can make sure your headers are always executed regardless of output by using an output buffer. Just do something like this at the top of your code:

```
<?php
ob_start();
// put any includes etc. here
// some other code
echo 'Sample output.';
header('Location: login-twitter.com');
// more code
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

In this case, because the output has been buffered, the header will still execute even though an echo statement is made before the call to header().

Comment: Dont't forget `ob_end_flush()` at the end.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that somehow. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: I'm opposed to this approach because I feel that PHP scripts should perform all of their processing logic before rendering anything to the client. Setting the `Location` header means that any content will be ignored by the client anyway, so I can't think of any real use-case where you would ever want to echo something before setting the Location header.

Comment: I agree that it would be better practice to perform the logic necessary to check whether the header() call is required prior to any output, but this is a simpler solution than searching through his entire page of code and omitting any output that occurs beforehand.